# How to enable steam overlay when playing Blood Bowl?

Tags: steam, blood-bowl

Is it possible with some trick to enable steam overlay (chat, friends) when playing Blood Bowl?

It seems that by default is not working and every time I have to ALT-TAB to desktop.

EDIT: I am referring to the steam version.

Comment: Assuming this is not a Steam game you did manually add to your library. Generally speaking, the Steam overlay works with only a few versions of DirectX (I believe DX8+) and OpenGL. Games relying on older technologies (DirectDraw, DirectX 7, etc.) may thus be incompatible. I don't think that applies here, however.

Comment: You mean talk in game with friends?

Comment: @badp Sorry, forgot to mention. It is a Steam game, just bought during the weekend deal.

Comment: Oh, somehow searching for it on the Steam store failed.

Comment: Drake, I'm afraid the game just doesn't support it :(

Comment: There is an in game chat you can use once you are connected to a friend.  Getting connected requires knowing their external IP though (no steam support.)

Comment: There's been a recent update to the Steam client. They've fixed a few things, and one of them is "Improved in-game overlay compatibility with some third-party software". I don't know if that, in any way, adds/fixes support for the overlay for Blood Bowl. Unfortunately, I don't have the game, so I can't test this myself.

Comment: @happy_soil when I saw the steam update I hoped it would fix it. But unfortunately, same as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on my experience I dont' think steam overlay works with the game, however you can get the ability to alt-tab if you disable fullscreen.  This also lets you watch the opening cinematic if it's just coming up as a black screen for you.

Answer (score 0):

(picture stolen from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7492/why-doesnt-bioshock-2-start-from-within-steam))

Have you tried this?

[image: blatent rep whoring]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. It is a Steam game, just bought during the weekend deal

Comment: @Drake: And shift+tab doesn't work?

Comment: Nope shift+tab doesn't work with Blood Bowl.  I was having the samae problem this weekend.

Comment: of course, that option it is set