# Why doesn't Bioshock 2 start from within steam?

Tags: steam, windows-7, technical-issues, bioshock-2

My question is similar to but a little different from this one: [Bioshock on Steam Hangs on Startup](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/bioshock-on-steam-hangs-on-startup)

I couldn't find anything in the steam / bioshock forums or troubleshooting manuals about this... Neither could I find any log files that *Bioshock 2* generates.

I recently got Bioshock 2 via Steam. When starting it from within Steam, the only thing I see is the launcher and the game binary appearing and (about 30s later) disappearing again in Process Explorer.

The strange thing is, that I **can** start Bioshock 2 from Windows 7's Start menu.

I tried around with admin priviliges, to no avail.

Using Steam's function to *Verify the integrity of the game files* was a mistake. It apparently restored the files that were updated when installing the patch that was forced on me by the *Games For Windows Live* framework that *Bioshock 2* appears to be glued to. I'm currently trying to recover from this by removing and completely re-downloading the game from steam.

My system is a 64bit Windows 7.

Comment: Good question with plenty of info included. You get an upvote but no answer I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, in fact there isn't even a question in the text, although one understands what is wanted.

Comment: @Stampede I modified the title, there you go :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the Steam Community feature conflicts with Microsoft's Games For Windows Live in-game overlay.
I disabled it and it worked.

[image]