# Steam Wont Open Bioshock 2

Tags: steam, bioshock-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't Bioshock 2 start from within steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7492/why-doesnt-bioshock-2-start-from-within-steam)

Windows 7 32 bit.
Trying to open Bioshock 2 within the Library menu in Steam.
The Securom launcher opens, then the executable itself. Then the entire thing crashes. No splash screen or anything, just a quick appearance in the task manager and both then disappear.

I've tried...

- checking the integrity of the files - all were good
- opening the game with '-dx9'
- deleting the roaming data.
- uninstalling, removing the Securom data, then
  reinstalling
- reinstalling drivers (NVIDIA 260.99)
- reinstalling Visual C++ ATL and other libs

It used to run fine. I think that I haven't been able to play ever since I installed the 260.99 driver.

Anyone run into a similar problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Rapture 3D, and reinstalling it from the official [Blue Ripple Sound website](http://www.blueripplesound.com/index.php?target=support).