# Resize Steam Overlay

Tags: steam, burnout-paradise

When opening a shortcut to Burnout Paradise from the Steam Big-Picture Mode, the size of the overlay is inconsistent.

Is there a way to set it to be a consistent size so it will always be small and never take up 1/4 of the screen with notifications?

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview with Steam Beta if that makes a difference

Comment: An 'Insider Preview' OS version with Beta version of Steam... have you tried this on official release versions? Also what is the screen resolution set to? Does burnout paradise have any graphical settings (and if so, what are THEY set to). Lots of things could be going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The Big Picture skin itself is not actually modifiable [at least not as of yet] because everything is reset when the client starts.

The best option, AFAIK, would probably be to use some [command-line options](https://gist.github.com/davispuh/6600880) for Big Picture mode:

- `-480p` - Run tenfoot in 480p rather than 1080p
- `-720p` - Run tenfoot in 720p rather than 1080p
- `-bigpicture` - Start in Steam Big Picture mode
- `-fulldesktopres` - Run tenfoot in full desktop resolution rather than 1080p, overrides `-720p` as well.
- `-nobigpicture` - Start in regular mode (force Big Picture mode off)
- `-tenfoot` - Start in Steam Big Picture mode
- `-windowed` - Run Steam tenfoot mode in a window rather than a fullscreen borderless window

I think `-bigpicture -fulldesktopres` should work for you (or `-tenfoot` instead of `-bigpicture`). These can be added to a shortcuts 'Target' to make it easy -- otherwise you'll have to use the command-line and open `Steam.exe` with the args you choose, which is what Mac is forced to do (`open -a Steam.app --args argsgohere`), and possibly Linux too but I don't know because I don't know Linux well enough.

Also not sure if this will help with the notifications being massive; if not they may be part of an editable portion of the skin but I wouldn't count on it because BP has it's own overlay definition AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to Disable it completely, its the only way to influence size of it.
If you can live with notifications on the screen, you may search for an option to move it to the other part of screen, to not interfere with games GUI.

Refer to screenshot from https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7519/171544